# Picking the latest and earliest dates via XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have a requirement where in I need to pick the latest Completion Date and Earliest Required Date in a set of records (User-Curriculum unique combination). I'm trying to use XSLT but no luck yet in getting it 100% correct. Please see sample payload and expected output below.

[Sample Payload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzY5y.jpg)

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30RfV.jpg)

I was able to get the correct completion date but keep on having the wrong value for Required Date. Hope somebody can help. Thanks

This is the code I used.

Code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns0="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:key name="group-key" match="Employee" use="concat(User, '|', Curriculum_ID)"/>
    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Employee[generate-id() = generate-id(key('group-key', concat(User, '|', Curriculum_ID))[1])]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Employee"/>
    <xsl:template match="ns0:Message2">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="root[1]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ns0:Message2/root"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please post the input example and the expected output **as code** within your question, not as pictures in external links.

Comment: Please tell us whether dates such as 12/5/2021 are in D/M/Y or M/D/Y format. (Ideally, avoid ambiguous formats and use ISO dates).

Comment: Hi. The dates are in MM-DD-YYYY format